# PostgreSQL select a record that not pass the condition

Tags: postgresql, select, partitioning, postgresql-14

I have partitioned a table named `Order` into two partitions, `Order_open` and `Order_close`.

I run following query on `Order` table to retrieve the related record `("orderID"='e641d634-5c6c-4c75-97a1-cb1b999295dc')` stored in  `Order_open`:

```
SELECT "orderID" FROM "Order" WHERE "orderID"='e641d634-5c6c-4c75-97a1-cb1b999295dc';
```

The result is so weird and intangible. Instead of receiving one row, I receive 2 rows! And the second row does not pass the condition! I do not understand why:

```
-[ RECORD 1]--+-------------------------------------
orderID       | e641d634-5c6c-4c75-97a1-cb1b999295dc
-[ RECORD 2]--+-------------------------------------
orderID       | e641d634-5c6c-4c75-97a1-cb1b999295dc
```

Because of the strange results with my first query, I try another query:

```
SELECT "orderID", "modifiedAt", "statusID" FROM "Order" WHERE "orderID"='e641d634-5c6c-4c75-97a1-cb1b999295dc';
```

And the result is:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------
orderID    | e641d634-5c6c-4c75-97a1-cb1b999295dc
modifiedAt | 2023-04-26 18:19:25.052157
statusID   | 101
-[ RECORD 2 ]------------------------------------
orderID    | 79b11a31-277e-4061-9b69-ee668dd9fb74
modifiedAt | 2023-04-27 07:42:32.493426
statusID   | 204
```

So weird! Another try with this query:

```
SELECT "orderID", "modifiedAt", "statusID" FROM "Order" WHERE "orderID"='79b11a31-277e-4061-9b69-ee668dd9fb74';
```

And the result:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------
orderID    | 79b11a31-277e-4061-9b69-ee668dd9fb74
modifiedAt | 2023-04-27 07:42:32.493426
statusID   | 204
```

Note 1: Second record `("orderID"='79b11a31-277e-4061-9b69-ee668dd9fb74')` is stored in `Order_close` partition

Note 2: The `orderID` column is unique in each partitions

Note 3: I need a solution to query from `Order`

Note 4: PostgreSQL 14.7

Comment: I think you need to redact less. Post it as text after changing whatever you want to hide.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middle example looks like index corruption.  You can probably fix it with a REINDEX, but if your indexes are corrupt I would worry about what else has also gotten corrupted.

Upgrading the OS glibc which implements collations can cause index corruption, but I doubt that that would apply to UUID types.  Flaky hardware can also cause index corruption, but if your hardware is flaky you will have no end of troubles and just reindexing will cover them up, not fix them.

In your first example, you say the 2nd row doesn't meet the condition, but it does.  You also object to there being two of them, but don't explain why that is objectionable.

Comment: Thank you. the first query and the second query are same, just selected columns are different. also I restore a backup to my local to recognize our error, and there is any new transaction on the database. I query this the first uuid directly from `Order_open` 
 and get just 1 row from it. as the same I query the first uuid from `Order_close` and getting no record!

Comment: Your first example might choose a different index from your 2nd one, and the index it choose was not corrupted.  For example, if you have two indexes containing "orderID", the first might choose the smaller of them, while the 2nd could choose a large one but which can satisfy an index-only-scan for the selected columns.  EXPLAIN on the queries could clarify if that is the case.

Comment: Did you restore a logical backup (taking with pg_dump) or a physical backup (taken with pg_basebackup or similar)?  Only the 2nd of those would be expected to preserve index corruption.

Comment: I apologize for the late response!

As you guest, I resorted from physical backup.

Comment: I employed the 'REINDEX' command, which resolved the failure. To gain further clarity, I conducted additional tests by restoring the backup once more. Then, I created a new index named 'duplicated_unique_orderID' on the 'orderID' column within the 'Order_close' table, without reindexing or dropping the old index. Upon executing the query, the result was accurate, with no rows returned from 'Order_close' as expected, and one row from 'Order'. I further investigated by examining the query plan using 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE', which indicated the utilization of the 'duplicated_unique_orderID' index.

Comment: However, upon dropping the 'duplicated_unique_orderID' index, the query reverted to producing an incorrect result similar to before.  The query plan  indicated the utilization of the old index. I then ran 'REINDEX' on the old index, and the problem was successfully rectified.
Based on these findings, it seems that the 'REINDEX' solution is indeed effective.

Comment: However, the root cause of the failure remains unresolved. Regarding your mention of `flaky hardware`, could you please provide clarification? Are you suggesting that it might be related to issues within virtualization solutions? For context, I am running PostgreSQL within a Kubernetes environment, with TrueNAS utilizing the ZFS filesystem